# MySQL起動時に「プラグインテーブルが存在しない」エラーが発生する

Tags: mysql

プログラミング超初心者のtoshimizuという者です。

つい先ほど似たような質問をし、回答を得ることが出来ましたが、再び別のエラーにぶつかってしまった為、改めて質問させていただきます。初心者な分、ご容赦下さい。

自分のPCにMySQLを導入しようとしてみたのですが、MySQLをインストールし、起動を試みた際、「mysqlのプラグインテーブルが存在しません」、「アップグレードして下さい」といったエラーが出てしまいます。
よしんばプラグインテーブルを作ればいいのだとして、どこに作ったらいいのかも分かりません。
原因または解決策をご存知の方はいらっしゃいませんか。

私の行った手順は以下の通りです。

(1) MySQLのサイト(https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)　から「Windows (x86, 64-bit), ZIP Archive」　をダウンロード。

(2) PCのDドライブに、MySQL専用のフォルダを作成し、フォルダ内にzipファイルを展開

(3) 同フォルダ内に、「data」、「logs」、「temp」、「mydata」フォルダを作成。さらに「my.ini」ファイルを作成し、参考記事に記載されていたコードをコピーペースト、さらに自分のPC環境に合わせて編集済。

(4) 管理者モードでコマンドプロンプトを起動。MySQLをインストールしたフォルダに移動し、以下のコマンドでMySQLを初期化。

```
bin\mysqld --initialize-insecure --user=mysql
```

(5) 以下のコマンドでMySQLを起動しようとしました。

```
bin\mysqld --defaults-file=".\my.ini" --console
```

すると、以下のようなエラーメッセージがでてしまいます。

```
2019-11-28T12:30:53.235246Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] 
D:\myplace\01_server\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.18) starting as process 2256
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2019-11-28T12:30:54.505401Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010735] [Server] Could not open the mysql.plugin table. Please perform the MySQL upgrade procedure.
2019-11-28T12:30:54.580612Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010015] [Repl] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2019-11-28T12:30:54.758654Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010015] [Repl] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2019-11-28T12:30:54.789074Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-11-28T12:30:54.793681Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010441] [Server] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
2019-11-28T12:30:54.795536Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013129] [Server] A message intended for a client cannot be sent there as no client-session is attached. Therefore, we're sending the information to the error-log instead: MY-001146 - Table 'mysql.component' doesn't exist
2019-11-28T12:30:54.798796Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013129] [Server] A message intended for a client cannot be sent there as no client-session is attached. Therefore, we're sending the information to the error-log instead: MY-003543 - The mysql.component table is missing or has an incorrect definition.
2019-11-28T12:30:54.803699Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010326] [Server] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
2019-11-28T12:30:54.805593Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010952] [Server] The privilege system failed to initialize correctly. For complete instructions on how to upgrade MySQL to a new version please see the 'Upgrading MySQL' section from the MySQL manual.
2019-11-28T12:30:54.810116Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-11-28T12:30:55.747382Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] D:\myplace\01_server\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.18)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

MySQLをインストールするにあたって、以下のサイトの記事を参考にしています。

[Windows10にzipのMySQLをインストールして起動する方法　Qiita](https://qiita.com/KOJI-YAMAMOTO/items/02af20e7b5cd27932a27)

原因を確かめるため、以下のようなテストを行ってみましたが、問題の解決には至りませんでした。

(a)

```
2019-11-28T12:30:53.235246Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] D:\myplace\01_server\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.18) starting as process 2256
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
```

「mysqlのプラグインが存在しません」と書いてあったので、mysqld.exeというファイルを編集すればいいのかと思ったのですが、開いてもすぐに消えてしまいます。

(b)

```
2019-11-28T12:30:54.505401Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010735] [Server] Could not open the mysql.plugin table. Please perform the MySQL upgrade procedure.
```

「MySQLをアップグレード手順を実行してください」とあり、関連する情報を調べてみたのですが、自分の理解力では解決には至りませんでした。

ちなみに、MySQLをインストールしようとした際、ネット上の色々な記事を参考にさせていただいているのですが、上で参照したQiitaの記事のやり方を踏襲する前に、別のやり方でMySQLをインストールしようとしたことがあるのですが、結局うまくいかず、今のやり方をしようとしています。

なので、PCのダウンロードファイル(Cドライブ)が以下のようになっている状態です。

mysql-8.0.18-winx64.zip　(←今現在取り組んでいるMySQLファイルの展開元のzipファイル)
mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.18.0 (1)　
mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.18.0　(←その前にインストールしようとして断念したインストーラー)

これが何か影響しているのでしょうか。ご指摘いただけたら幸いです。

なお、私の環境は以下の通りです。
【PC:Inspiron3471, メモリ:8GB, OS:Windows 10 Home(64ビット)】

また、こういった問題にあたった時に、どのように解決したら良いでしょうか。教えていただけると助かります。
重ね重ね初歩的な質問で申し訳ありませんが、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score -1):

自己解決できました。
協力してくださった方、ありがとうございました。

Comment: 自己解決した場合は具体的にどのような手順で解決したか記述してください。同じような問題で躓いた人向けに、わかりやすい形に記述していただけると良いと思います。